# Count no of child nodes for every node

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-tree

Given a tree:

```
      F
    /   \
   C     E
  / \   /
 A   B D
```

I want to count no of child nodes for every nodes. What will be optimized algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

If the child count is supposed to include grandchildren, do a postorder traversal, recursively counting branch sizes in O(n):

```
int countChildren(Node node) {
  int leftCount = node.left == null ? 0 : (countChildren(root.left) + 1);
  int rightCount = node.right == null ? 0 : (countChildren(root.right) + 1);

  int totalChildren = leftCount + rightCount;

  System.out.println(node.name + ":" + totalChildren);

  return totalChildren;
}
```

Comment: This will give total no of count of root node. Isn't it?

Comment: It will give the total count of children including grandchildren of any node. For F, it will return 5. For C it will return 2. For E, it will return 1. For A, B and D, it will return 0. Is that not what you wanted? If so, please clarify.

Comment: I was given a problem to find direct report to manager. Anyone in upper hierarchy is manager. We need to print How many employees each manager manages.
Answer should be printed as:

Comment: F:5
C:2
E:1
A:0
B:0
D:0
How to use this tree to find this solution. Based on given information I have formed tree given above.

Comment: I have added a corresponding print statement (assuming node.name is A, B, C etc). To get the desired output, call the method with a reference to the root node.

Comment: Thanks.
One more quest:
   
Map<String,Long>  hashTable1= new HashMap<String,Long>();
    String result="";
    int n=scan.nextInt();
    String name;
    long ph;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
    name=scan.next();
    ph=scan.nextLong();
    hashTable1.put(name, ph);
    }
    System.out.println("1");

    String s=null;
    while(scan.hasNext())
    {
   s=scan.next();
   if (hashTable1.containsKey(s)) 
   {
   result=(s+"="+hashTable1.get(s))+"\n";
   }
   else    
   result="Not Found\n";
    }
       
System.out.println(result);

Comment: In this code I am reading key value pairs first.
Then there will be N searches (User will enter key to search). If NextLine is pressed (empty string) we have to stop search.
please check what is wrong.

Comment: This is really hard to read unformatted and doesn't really seem related. I'd recommend to create a new question for this.